# Is it possible to simulate a fair coin with a finite number of tossing of a biased one?

Tags: proof-techniques, probability-theory, randomized-algorithms, randomness, probabilistic-algorithms

It is a classic problem to simulate a fair coin with a biased one.

According to [Fair Coin (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin),

> John von Neumann gave the following procedure:
>
> 1. Toss the coin twice.
> 2. If the results match, start over, forgetting both results.
> 3. If the results differ, use the first result, forgetting the second.

In the worst case, the procedure may not terminate.

***Problem:*** Is it possible to design an algorithm which guarantees termination in the worst case? What is the technique to solve such an impossibility problem?

Comment: No, it’s not possible, even when you know the bias of the coin to be, say, 1/3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  Suppose the bias of the coin is $1/3$, and suppose you could guarantee termination.  Then there would be some $n$ such that this always terminates after $n$ coin flips.  Let $S$ denote the set of flip-sequences that causes your algorithm to output 0 (so that $\overline{S}$ is the set of flip-sequences that causes your algorithm to output 1).  The probability of your algorithm outputting 0 is equal to the probability of getting a flip-sequence in $S$, which is a sum of the form

$$\sum_{x \in S} {a_x \over 3^n}$$

where each $a_x$ is an integer.  Thus the probability of outputting 0 has the form $b/3^n$ where $b$ is an integer.  We want this to be $1/2$, for your algorithm to produce an unbiased bit of output.  However since $3^n$ is odd, there is no integer $b$ such that $b/3^n = 1/2$.  Therefore, no such algorithm can exist.

Comment: See [this question and its answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901886/simulating-a-fair-coin-toss-using-a-biased-coin-in-fixed-number-of-tosses) for an extension of this argument that works for all rational biases (other than 1/2).